# cloud function onUpdate inside document

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

it's possible to trigger onUpdate only on a document field?, I want to check if there's changes on the  images field, that is an array, if yes, how I write the document path

```
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}/????')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onUpdate triggers will fire when **anything** inside a matched document changes.  It doesn't matter what changed.

It's not possible to narrow a trigger down to a particular field.  Triggers can only match an entire document.  If you want to know if something changed in a field, you will need to write code to compare the "before" and "after" snapshots.

Comment: there are more fields inside the collection, I just didn't want to show them

Comment: Sure, that still doesn't really change my answer.  You can't target a specific field in a document for a trigger, you have to target a document as a whole.

Comment: okay, but I want to know if is possible to watch for changes only on the images, not on all the collection

Comment: No, it's not possible.